# How can I use web service methods to show rdl reports on report viewer remotely and instead of URL and Report Path?

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-viewer2010

I need to know is there any way that we could use SSRS web Service methods to use as URL for Report viewer? In better way I have a rdl report published on SSRS Web server and from the client side I have a report viewer to get that report from SSRS web server and shows it on my WinForm. Report viewer uses of remote processing mode and URL of the Web server and Path of rdl file. How ever I want to use Web Service methods (if there is any) instead of URL and Path to show my report on my Winform by Report viewer is any one expert knows how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in reporting services
you can use the report service to get the information of any item in your Report server,
To open(View)any report you will need the report path .

Thanks ,
Sufian